# How much space a normal SQL Server database file takes on HDD

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I want to use a remote/online SQL server Database service for testing purpose, I am currently planning to use AppHarbor's service for the purpose which provides 20MB of free database space.

The test database which I want to create will have:

- Around 20-25 tables
- One table wont have any more than 20-25 fields
- fields will only have primitive types e.g. varchar, number, booean, etc. i.e. no image/file types etc.
- One tables wont have any more than 100-200 records.
- and a bunch of constraints required at database level.

Is 20MB enough for creating and maintaining a database like this or not?
If not is there any other better and preferably free option to host a small scale SQL server database.

Comment: Saif, Might be this link useful to you.
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/estimating-disk-space-requirements-for-databases/

Comment: Get yourself the free version of SQL Server (Express?), create your database, fill it with test data according to your needs and do the following: Right mouse button on the database -> Reports -> Standard Reports -> Disk Usage. And by the way: Asking for alternatives is not very well received on SO, your question might get closed. Better ask for alternatives over at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That's only half the story.You also have a transaction log (.LDF) that records all the changes to your databases. Quite often this file gets larger than the .MDF

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid You are right. But if that first estimate (that also includes the space for the transaction log) is roughly 20MB the given space will never be enough ;)

Comment: Yes that's true - my comment was adressed more to the OP

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact schema it is impossible to estimate. I suggest you first create the database localy fill it with sample data and run

```
EXEC sp_spaceused
```

You can then have a rough estimate how much you'd be able to scale.